# turn up to the next level in java programming server/client

Tags: java, frameworks

I studied Java and I'm pretty sure I'm ready to turn up to the next level. I made software using JFC to save datas and class like `Server` and `ServerSocket` to create connection server/client. But It seems to simple and less performant.Well I know would pass to something more business side and used in working environment. I found Hiberante framework to connect to database and so save data there and retrieve them. But now I'm looking for something to create software server/client side using some frameworks.which are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some alternatives.
http://java-source.net/open-source/web-frameworks